# Issue with jQuery deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm facing an issue with deferred usage where 2 nested function that should wait for each other actually run in the wrong order silently.
I cant' figure out where I mix return promise.

So here is what I try to achieve. In a mobile Cordova app, when user enter the Game view, I got a function that download question in WebSql, and I want then to retrieve one question, and then my slider function load the content.
So I nested the `getQuestion` function in the `.done()` event.

```
router.addRoute('game', function () {
      'use strict';
      //Reload Question List when User enter the Game view.
      questionService.initialize().done(
        //Now we got question, initialize the Game View
        questionService.getQuestion().done(
          function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            slider.slidePage(new GameView(data).render().$el);
          })
      );
```

Here is how I use the `$.Deferred()` in both function. First I declare my `$.Deferred()` and at the end of the function I return the promise.

But my `getQuestion()` in code below does not wait for the `initialize()` function to end before start.

Where did I mixed up my promise return?

```
var getQuestions = function(param) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    param = param;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myserver',
        data: {
            region: uRegion
        },
        success: function(value, status) {
            //do something with value
            this.db = window.openDatabase('database details');
            this.db.transaction(function(tx) {
                storeQuestion(tx);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject('Transaction error: ' + error);
            }, function() {
                //Transaction success
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        },
        error: function(textStatus, exception) {}
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the success callback handler. As per current implementation your are invoking  `getQuestion()` immediately.

Use anonymous function, rest its fine

```
//Reload Question List when User enter the Game view.
questionService.initialize().done(function(){
  //Now we got question, initialize the Game View
    questionService.getQuestion().done(
      function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        slider.slidePage(new GameView(data).render().$el);
      })
});
```